# Can't use the <component /> tag helper on a Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, blazor

I'm using DotNetCore 3.1 and Razor Pages.

I want to use a Razor Component I created on the `Index.Razor` page, but have it use the 'Static' rendering mode.

According to the documentation:

> To render a component from a **page** or view, use the Component Tag
>   Helper:
>
> ```
> <component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" 
>     param-IncrementAmount="10" />
> ```

As you can see below, I can render my component (named Lister) using it's name as a tag (`<Lister></Lister>`). I am unable, however, to use the `<component />` tag helper to render it.

[image: Can't use component tag helper]

It neither highlights the syntax as a recognized tag helper nor actually renders it if I run the page.

When I do run the page, it does not show the component, it instead appears as

`<component type="typeof(Lister)" render-mode="Static"></component>`

in the page source.

In another project, I was able to render the same component (with the same syntax) in an MVC View (`.cshtml`) file.

---

Edit:

Ok, so I think what I missed/messed up is that **my `Index.razor` file is not a Razor Page, but rather a routable Razor Component.**

**I mistakenly took a Blazor project to be a Razor Pages one.**

Razor Pages have `.cshtml` file types

Razor Components have `.razor` file types (and can confusingly have the @page directive)

Razor Components have no access to the `<component />` tag helper, and must use other Razor Components via `<theNameOfIt></theNameOfIt>`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component Tag Helper is not a Blazor object. The concept of tag helper or html helper in Blazor does not exist. This is the domain of Razor Pages and MVC. In Blazor we have a Component Model.

Ordinarily you should use the component Tag Helper within the _Host.cshtml file to render the Razor App component.

You can't embed the component Tag Helper in your Index.razor component. You can't use the component Tag Helper in Blazor. The _Host.cshtml file is not Blazor. It's a Razor Pages file that starts a Blazor application...